# iText problem displaying unicode characters

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I need some help with iText on android. I'm creating a PDF and need it to display characters like: ā, ū, ē, ķ, č. Here is the code I'm using to create the custom font.

```
BaseFont bf;
{
    try {
        bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/CAMBRIA.TTC", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Font smallFont = new Font(bf, 12);
```

And here is an example of how I'm using it.

```
PdfPTable table_start = new PdfPTable(3);

    PdfPCell name = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Objekts: " + view0.getText().toString(), smallFont));
```

When I display the String I get from another activity in the view, the text looks normal but when the PDF is created all the special characters are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually fairly simple. All I had to do was to put a font that supports Unicode characters in the assets folder and change:

```
bf = BaseFont.createFont("c:/windows/fonts/CAMBRIA.TTC", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

to

```
 bf_smallfont = BaseFont.createFont("assets/times.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

1. Convert your Unicode text into ANSI font supported text
2. Then generate your pdf using your ANSI font

### First you have to convert Your Unicode Text like Below:

```
formattedMsg =  ANSIObj.ConvertToANSIText(outletObj.banglaName);

public String Convert(String line) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    //Your conversion Code
    return line;
}
```

### Then Create PDF

```
public void CreateBanglaMemoTableFormat(List<PDFTableData> items) {
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate());

    try {
        setYourFont();
        doc = new Document(new Rectangle(818.3f, 609f));


        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyPDF";

        File dir = new File(path);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

        File file = new File(dir, "newPDFFile.pdf");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

        //open the document
        doc.open();

         Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph();
         p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_LEFT);
         p1.setFont(f_textFont);
         p1.add(formattedMsg);

         PdfPTable tt = masteraTableCreation(p1);

         doc.add(tt);
        }

    } catch (DocumentException de) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
    } finally {
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

### Set your font

```
 public void setYourFont() throws DocumentException, IOException {
    try {
        bf = BaseFont.createFont("/fontname", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        f_textFont = new Font(bf, 10);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

### Cell Creation for PDF

```
private PdfPTable masteraTableCreation(Paragraph celV1) {
    float[] columnWidths = {236};
    PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(columnWidths);
    mainTable.getDefaultCell().setPaddingRight(5);
    mainTable.setTotalWidth(786f);
    mainTable.setLockedWidth(true);

    PdfPCell cell;

    //region Row 1
    // column 1
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(celV1));
    cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    mainTable.addCell(cell);

    return mainTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used BaseFont.IDENTITY_H in encoding parameter in call to BaseFont.createFont API and it worked.

Comment: The OP also used IDENTITY_H. His issue essentially was that he used a font path from some Windows system "c:/windows/fonts/CAMBRIA.TTC" on Android, see his answer.